# How would you say "x says hi" in Japanese?

Tags: translation, phrases

I've given this some thought but due to both my lack of knowledge in Japanese (still studying atm, although in Japan for a year so that should improve) and just not being able to come up with anything that sounds right with what I do know, I'm not even sure if this is like a thing to say in Japanese. Either that or I'm just getting tunnel vision on this and missing an extremely simple way of translating this.

But so yeah, is there a way to say like "Bob says hi by the way," like when you were talking about one person with Bob earlier and then Bob tells you to extend his greetings to that person the next time you meet?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> "Bob says hi by the way."

- 「ところで、ボブが**よろしく**って。」
- 「そうだ、ボブが**よろしく**って。」

or

- 「ところで、ボブが**ハロー**って。」

or something similar.

The above sentences are a casual way of saying the first sentence below:

> ところで、ボブが「よろしく」**と**言っていましたよ
>   ところで、ボブが「よろしく」**って**言っていたよ
>   ところで、ボブが「よろしく」**って**

Comment: It's almost always ～ **が** 「よろしく」と/って言ってたよ ( *informal* ) except in rare cases like 「ボブは『よろしく』って言ってたけど、トムは何も言ってなかったよ。」 where the は is acting as a contrastive.

Comment: I agree that が is much more commonly used. However, I thought that the context of the OP uses "By the way," 「ところで」as an interjection implying a change of topic (as in, we weren't talking about Bob until just now when I remembered that he told me to say hi to you), making は more appropriate for this scenario. What do you think?

Comment: I don't think the use of ところで  has any bearing on the choice of the topic/subject marker, at least not in this case.

Comment: @goldbrick I've edited the answer. Does this look alright to you?

Comment: It most certainly does to me!

Comment: But maybe while I'm at it, I may take issue with 「おっ」  as a translation of "by the way"... ところで and そうだ are fine.